# How to publish only when on master branch under Travis and sbt 0.13

Tags: sbt, travis-ci

I'm using Travis for continuous build and integration.

```
after_success:
- sbt publish
```

While we want Travis to build all of our branches and pull requests, we only want it to `publish` when on `master` branch.

```
publishTo <<= version { (v: String) =>
  val nexus = s"asdf"
  /* Don't let Travis publish when building pull requests.
   * $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" if it's not a pull request.  So we wan't publishTo to be
   * None when TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST != false.
   */
  if(Try(sys.env("TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST")).getOrElse("false") != "false")
    None
  /* Don't let Travis publish except when building master. */
  if(Try(sys.env("TRAVIS_BRANCH")).map(_ != "master").getOrElse(false))
    None
  else if(v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "snapshots")
  // don't let Travis publish releases, either
  else if(Try(sys.env("TRAVIS")).getOrElse("false") == "true")
    None
  else
    Some("releases"  at nexus + "releases")
})
```

The problem with this approach is that Travis compiles branches twice because it fails publishing at the very last step.

How can Travis be completely prevented from running `sbt publish` when on non-`master` branch?

Comment: Yes we are using sbt 0.13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd make a new task for it, and call that in Travis.

```scala
val publishMasterOnTravis = taskKey[Unit]("publish master on travis")

def publishMasterOnTravisImpl = Def.taskDyn {
  import scala.util.Try
  val travis   = Try(sys.env("TRAVIS")).getOrElse("false") == "true"
  val pr       = Try(sys.env("TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST")).getOrElse("false") == "true"
  val branch   = Try(sys.env("TRAVIS_BRANCH")).getOrElse("??")
  val snapshot = version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")
  (travis, pr, branch, snapshot) match {
    case (true, false, "master", true) => publish
    case _                             => Def.task ()
  }
}

publishMasterOnTravis := publishMasterOnTravisImpl.value

publishTo := {
  val nexus = s"asdf"
  if (version.value.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) 
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "snapshots") 
  else
    Some("releases" at nexus + "releases")
}
```

The key here is using `Def.taskDyn`, which lets me call `publish` at the tail position without depending on it. `publishTo` would be plain logic.

Comment: Great answer, Eugene. Lot to learn from. Since sbt 0.13's in use, I'm a bit concerned with `publishTo <<= version {}` construct as opposed to `:=` and `version.value` inside. Is this on purpose or just a leftover from copying the question's body?

Comment: I left `publishTo` as old school style on purpose, since the OP looks like he's already familiar with it. I'd recommend `:=` esp for newcomers but I don't demonize `<<=`.

Comment: I think "the old school style" will stay longer in use when it's used by you and others in answers as a ready-to-copy-and-paste solution. I think it should be banned for the purpose of a better understanding sbt (and to stop confusing newcomers).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Updated to sbt 0.13 syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think it will eventually pay off.

Comment: Looks like TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST now returns an id of the pull request so you need to change your code to `Try(sys.env("TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST")).getOrElse("false") != "false"`

Answer (score 44):

You might consider handling this outside of your publish script:

```
after_success:
  - test $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST == "false" && test $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" && sbt publish
```

Comment: This is a much simpler answer, IMO.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this solution **will not** fail the build in case of failure in publishing....which is not always ok.